# Heroku AWS s3 bucket name

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

> The aws.s3.bucket name should be changed to something unique and
>   related to your application. For instance, the demo application uses
>   the value com.heroku.devcenter-java-play-s3 which would have to be
>   changed to something else if you want to run the demo yourself.

I am trying to use S3 with Heroku. I'm also using Play2 Framework with Scala. I used the plugin displayed in here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-s3-for-file-uploads-with-java-and-play-2#s3-plugin-for-play-2

One thing on my config file is I need to set up these three parameters:

```
aws.access.key=${?AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
aws.secret.key=${?AWS_SECRET_KEY}
aws.s3.bucket=com.something.unique
```

I found the access and secret key on AWS console, but wht is this `s3.bucket`? I did have assigned a name to my S3 bucket, but the format here looks like a website or a java package hierarchy. What should I put there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An S3 bucket is a storage container within the AWS S3 service.  You need to create the bucket with their web console or API before you can store data in S3.  All data lives within a bucket.

Once you have created your bucket, you need to configure your S3 client to use that bucket name where you want to store the data.

S3 bucket names are a global name space across S3.  They often use a dotted demarcation like a Java package or domain name, but it's an arbitrary convention some folks use.

You can use the same bucket in multiple environments if you are comfortable with leaking data between staging and production.  I recommend using separate S3 buckets for each environments.

Comment: I would also encourage the bucket name to be managed as a Heroku config variable (in turn exposed to your app as an environment variable). E.g., `heroku config:set AWS_S3_BUCKET=com.something.unique`. This will help ensure your local dev and Heroku dev/staging/prod environments don't overlap their data. Locally, you'd use a `.env` file and foreman to emulate the heroku config command.

Comment: @Winfield, well, am I right that buckets are independent between accounts? Am I right that if I want to start staging or production server, I don't need to create both staging and production buckets with one account on amazon?

Comment: S3 bucket names are a global name space across S3.  They often use a dotted demarcation like a Java package or domain name, but it's an arbitrary convention some folks use.  You can use the same bucket in multiple environments if you are comfortable with leaking data between staging and production.  I recommend using separate S3 buckets for each environments.